# Flask: Using WTForm on another Page than the one rendering the form itself

Tags: flask, flask-wtforms, flask-bootstrap

I have the following setup:

The rendering page:

```
@app.route('/one', methods=['GET'])
def one():
    form = AnyForm()
    return render_template(
        'form.html', form=form
    )
```

The template (stripped to the basic):

```
{{ wtf.quick_form(form, action=url_for('two')) }}
```

The route/function including the logic

```
@app.route('/two', methods=['POST'])
def two(form):
    print('FORMDATA: ' + form)
    return redirect(url_for('one'))
```

The error is:

```
TypeError: two() missing 1 required positional argument: 'form'
```

How do I handle this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to define the form on functuin `two` and populate it from post request that the function recieves, this way you dont need to get any argument

try this:

```
@app.route('/two', methods=['POST'])
def two():
    form = AnyForm(request.form)
    print('FORMDATA: ' + form)
    return redirect(url_for('one'))
```

and the way you tried, you have to give your `url_for` function a form argument like this

```
{{ wtf.quick_form(form, action=url_for('two', form=form)) }}
```

Im not sure if it works